# Checking the lyrics: The Neville Staple Band's Put Away Your Knives

Tags: lyrics

I am listening The Neville Staple Band's *Put Away Your Knives*

It has shown some lyrics but not all.
Could anyone help me complete the missed part (marked by three question marks)?
Thanks.

Stop your running about
Best you sort yourself out
Stop your running around
Taking knives out in town

(*) Do you see?
A message to the youth take heed
A message to you

You're growing into a man
Kids could be on your plan
???

(*)

Stop your fooling around
Guns and knives out in town
Don't you know what you're doing
??? People's life is in your hand (I'm not sure)

[2x]
Do you see?
A message to the youth take heed
A message to the youth take heed
A message to you

Comment: Lyrics are very similar to ["A message to you, Rudy"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Message_to_You_Rudy) by Dandy Livingstone. You could maybe use the lyrics of [that](https://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/specials/amessagetoyourudy.html) to fill in the missing bit of this

Comment: @Angst The missed three lines don't appear in "A message to you, Rudy". But I am surprised at the existence of this song. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I can work out from the video.

Kids could be on your plan
**But who are they expect to look up to**
**With a knife in your hand**

The line "But who are they.." is unclear as it seems to have too many words in the line.

Don't you know what you're doing
**People's lives in your hands**

Neville Staple was a key member of The Specials who had a bit with a [cover of A Message to You, Rudy in 1979](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Specials_discography). Nev has reworked the song following the [stabbing of his grandson](https://www.nme.com/news/music/the-specials-neville-staple-releases-knife-crime-song-after-grandson-was-stabbed-to-death-2464856) in an appeal to reduce knife crime.

Comment: Got it! Thanks for your help. I think it is "But who are they to look up to
With a blade in your hand". And thanks for the news. I like such kind of stories behind songs.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. The first line I had some difficulty with. The second line just mistyped the notes that I had transcribed.